# Q key sticky and not working right

Tags: laptop, keyboard

The q key on my laptop takes a long time to rise up after it has been pressed. I think there is something sticky under it. I have a IdeaPad S145-15AST. Are the keys removeable, and if so, how do I safely remove them?

Comment: You might be able to:  https://www.laptopkeys.com/KeyboardKeys.php/Lenovo/IdeaPad/S145-15   Generally better to replace the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible* to clean your keyboard, but the very small and very fragile mechanisms under the keys are... very small and very fragile.

A better idea is to purchase a replacement keyboard. Unless you have an accidental damage warranty, this sort of thing will not be covered by a warranty.

Comment: Is taking apart the entire laptop an option?

Comment: What do you mean? Does the laptop have to be fully disassembled to access the keyboard? The keys are not inside the laptop, and I presented two options.